# Syncing using Zumero with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, zumero

I need a solution, i have setup Zumero setting to syncing my mobile device SQLite data to SQL server and vice-versa, it run on test machine, but my requirement is to sync data using jQuery or Javascript code to trigger sync function of Zumero, is this possible? or we have to code in c#, or objective c, its not work in my case because i am using Apache Cordova (multi device hybrid app)which support multiple platforms.

I need the replacement of this in Javascript or jQuery, so that I can use it in cross platforms.

```
using Zumero;
    ZumeroClient.Sync(
  "/path/to/sqlite.db",   // full path to local db file
  null,
  "http://MY_ZUMERO_SERVER:8080",
  "test",                 // remote DBFile name
  null,
  null,
  null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Zumero *does* support Phonegap/Cordova. See the `phonegap` folder in the [Zumero for SQL Server SDK](http://zumero.com/dev-center/zss/#zssclientsdk).

You basically call a `sync()` function, passing in *success* and *error* callback functions:

```
zumero.sync("/data/data/com.example.myapp/mydb",
   "",
   "https://zss.example.com",
   "mydb",
   '{"scheme_type":"table", "table":"users"}',
   "user",
   "password",
   function() {
      // success
   },
   function(result) {
      // failure - result.code and result.message will
      // contain details
   }
);
```

Comment: i am getting success method but how could i check my synced database file where it will store on my system.

Comment: That's entirely up to you, your app, and your system's requirements. Zumero doesn't control where your database is stored.

Comment: Thank You Paul for assisting me.
But sorry to say, I think I have to move some customize solution rather than Zumero.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented my own syncing mechanism by using checksum of sql server, where I have created a table for checksum which keep sum of checksum for all tables data and we match the checksum from syncing end points, if any change in checksum value it implies syncing needed.